# Buildfire: Audio Player Service not creating timeUpdate events

Tags: javascript, audio, buildfire

https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-Audio-Player-Service

in `index.html`:

```
function Player() {} //make it global
Player.instance = buildfire.services.media.audioPlayer;
```

in the triggering function inside `player.js`

```
let track = {};
track.title = "Given Title";
track.url = <insert url here>;
track.image = <insert img.jpg url here>;
Player.instance.play(track);
```

when initializing the Media Player UI in `player.js`:

```
Player.instance.onEvent ( function(e){
    console.log(e.event);
    //other code goes here
};
```

Right now, on the offline tester, my media player works perfectly, updating the time, and adding the changes when I pause or play. Unfortunately, when I move it to the online tester and the actual app, my phone, and my client's phone don't receive the "timeUpdate" event. And I'm confirming that, with the code above, I DO get "play" and "pause" events, but not the "timeUpdate" event.

Can anyone confirm if this happens for them too, or if there are any fixes?

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about the Control Panel or the PWA version of your app?

Comment: Both. Offline (`buildfire run` on `sdk-master`), the timeUpdate works. I put it up into dev.buildfire, and test it on my app.buildfire. Some versions had it, others didn't. Right now it doesn't send "timeUpdate" So I thought "this must be one of those features that only work when published". On my phone, it works sometimes, but on my clients' phones, it doesn't.

Comment: I believe this was a bug in the system that was recently fixed. This should be rolled out this week. Give it a day or two if its still not fixed contact customer support to follow up

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is not with the code, but the server where the audio is hosted.  Try hosting the audio on a s3 or other cloud storage bucket instead of bundling it into the app (sorry can't comment yet)

Comment: Sadly, my audio IS hosted on an S3, or at least I think it is. Sample URL with the names removed'. `https://<client-name>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/<audio-name>.mp3`

Comment: I think there is an open ticket with this on the BuildFire Side. Talk to your account manager they should be able to push for it